# Pop to specific item in QtQuick StackView

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt5.2, qtquickcontrols

I am using Qt 5.2.1 on Android, and I have a main application window with code as below (the example is a bit contrived, but it illustrates accurately what I am doing):

```
property Component mainMenuView: MainMenuView {
    onMoviesSelected: {
        stackView.push(moviesListView)
    }
    onSettingsSeleted: { }
    onAboutSeleted: { }
}

property Component moviesListView: MovieListView {
    onMovieSelected: {
        stackView.push(movieDetailView)
    }
    onBack: stackView.pop()
}

property Component movieDetailView: MovieDetailView {
    onCreditsSelected: {
        stackView.push(personListView)
    }
    onBack: stackView.pop()
}

property Component personListView: PersonListView {
    onPersonSelected: {
        // Pending...
    }
    onBack: stackView.pop()
}
```

The idea is you choose from the menu, you see the movies. You choose from the movies, you see movie detail. You choose to view credits, you see the list of cast and crew. All of this uses a `StackView` and works just fine. The back button also works fine, popping off the views one at a time as you go back.

So now when I choose a particular person from the `personListView`, I want to skip right back to the `moviesListView` and miss out the intermediate `movieDetailView`. The idea is that the movie list now shows only the movies that include the selected person.

*I know that I could, any maybe should, just push another `moviesListView` in this case - but this example is contrived to describe the general issue.*

To do this, you can invoke the `StackView` `pop()` method and supply the 'item' you want to go back to - so I tried this:

```
property Component personListView: PersonListView {
    onPersonSelected: {
        stackView.pop(moviesListView)
    }
    onBack: stackView.pop()
}
```

When this runs, there are no error messages (so I assume it knows that `movieListView` is something that exists) but it pops back to the immediately previous view, i.e. the `movieDetailView`. It should miss out that view and show the `movieListView`.

If I try to pop back to the `mainMenuView`, it still just pops back to the immediately previous `movieDetailView`.

Is this somehow related to how I am using `Component` for my views and if so what should I do, or is something else wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug. I can reproduce it with this example:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

Rectangle {
    property Component mainMenuView: Button {
        text: "mainMenuView"
        onClicked: {
            Stack.view.push(moviesListView)
        }
    }

    property Component moviesListView: Button {
        text: "moviesListView"
        onClicked: {
            Stack.view.push(movieDetailView)
        }
    }

    property Component movieDetailView: Button {
        text: "movieDetailView"
        onClicked: {
            Stack.view.push(personListView)
        }
    }

    property Component personListView: Button {
        text: "personListView"
        onClicked: {
            // Wrong: goes to movieDetailView.
            Stack.view.pop(moviesListView)
            // Wrong: goes to mainMenuView.
//            Stack.view.pop({item: moviesListView})
        }
    }

    StackView {
        initialItem: mainMenuView
    }
}
```

I've created [QTBUG-39423](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-39423) for this.